# Unable to install node-expat in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, jenkins, npm, node-expat

I am trying to install dependencies of a Node project in my CI server that runs on RHEL. When I run npm install, I get the following error

```
> node-expat@2.3.16 install 
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tryout/workspace/myproject/node_modules/node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild

make ✖ ERR  Missing Makefile / Bakefile 
make ℹ info Run "make init" to generate a Makefile.
```

Node v7.10.0

NPM v5.4.2

node-expat v2.3.16

Comment: Did you use NPM to install the node-expat?

Comment: Yes. I used NPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling NodeJS version 8.0 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

FTR: `make ✖ ERR  Missing Makefile / Bakefile` is the output of an npm package called [`make`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make). Having it in the PATH confuses `node-gyp` and breaks the build.